# OMR sheet scanning using OpenCV in Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0

When I scan the OMR sheet to detect contours it is not detecting all rectangles. steps as below:

1. Loading color image
2. Convert to gray and resize
3. Blur the image using GaussianBlur
4. Edge detection using Canny
5. Finding contours
6. Visualizing the results

But it is not showing all rectangles. can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Attached OMR sheet for reference:

[image: Input OMR sheet]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question and add the code you use (see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Description of the steps without an actual implementation are not enough to get help here.

Comment: Checkout OMRChecker, an open source software to solve such problem, you can check the source code and project wiki for ideas. (Disclaimer: I'm the author for the project)

Answer (score 0):

My advice is as follows:

1. load image
2. img to gray
3. blur and canny
4. apply contour
5. print the contours and sort contours them
6. draw contours if they have the same area (since your region of interest all are the same shape)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread('test.png') #read image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #turn image to gray
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(3,3),0) #add blur
edges = cv2.Canny(blur,50,100) #find edges

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) #find contours
cv2.drawContours(img,contours,-1,(0,255,0),2) #draw contours
cv2.imshow('Contours in Green',img) #show contours in green

#Now you need to sort them out.
```

[image: Output of all the contours]